# How do I remove a specific part of a URL in a redirect?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, web, url-rewriting

Our hosting allows us to access specific accounts by appending the first eight letters of the account name after a tilde, after the IP of our server. So for example:

```
123.456.123.456/~examples
```

This also means we can access the site through this URL:

```
example.com/~examples
```

We have some basic .htaccess code to rewrite this to:

```
example.com/
```

What we want to do is the same, but for all URL's across the site, with a single rule in .htaccess. So for example:

```
example.com/~examples/about-us
```

Redirects to:

```
example.com/about-us
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Could you please accept the best answer for future visitors, or comment on the answers if your question isn't solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place this rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /~\w+/(\S+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,L,NE]
```

**You must use `%{THE_REQUEST}` variable** to match `~user` here otherwise Apache strips `~user` from `REQUEST_URI`. `THE_REQUEST` variable represents original request received by Apache from your browser and it doesn't get overwritten after execution of some rewrite rules. Example value of this variable is `GET /~user//index.php?id=123 HTTP/1.1`

Answer (score 1):

The following should do what you need:

```
RewriteRule    ^~examples\/?(.*)$    $1    [NC,L]
```

For more, see [URL Rewriting for Beginners](http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/).

Comment: You don't need to escape a forward slash `/`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /~example/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
RewriteRule ^~example/?(.*)$ $1 [L,QSA]
```

I find this a very handy guide for `Regex`s: http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html